# What are u_str, Recv-Q and Send-Q in ss output?

Tags: command-line, networking, 16.04

The `ss` command is very similar to `netstat` command but it is faster and more accurate than `netstat`.

```
monitoring-server@monitoring-server:~$ ss
Netid State      Recv-Q Send-      Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port       
u_str ESTAB      0      0          * 34006              * 34007
```

This is the first line of the ouptut. This command tells all the sockets open in the system.

Total on my system is 96 and 56 of them has `u_str` as `Netid`and rest have `tcp`.

What is this `u_str` here , Also please explain more about `Recv-Q` and `Send-Q`?

Answer (score 7):

`u_str` is a stream socket and equivalent to `netstat`'s SOCK_STREAM.

> SOCK_STREAM: This is a stream (connection) socket.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_socket):

> In computer operating systems, a stream socket is a type of interprocess communications socket or network socket which provides a connection-oriented, sequenced, and unique flow of data without record boundaries, with well-defined mechanisms for creating and destroying connections and for detecting errors.

Let's create a stream socket:

```
netcat -lU /tmp/streamsocket
```

Now run:

```
ss -an | grep streamsocket
```

It will output:

```
u_str  LISTEN     0      5      /tmp/streamsocket 123360      * 0
```

Simply put, it's the type of socket which can be "UDP" or "TCP" too. Let's create a UDP socket:

```
netcat -lu 127.0.0.1 8060
```

Now, `ss -l sport = 8060` will tell you that this one is a "UDP" instead of "u_str".

---

For the "Recv-Q" and "Send-Q" columns, consult `man 8 netstat`:

> Recv-Q
>          The count of bytes not copied by the user program connected to this socket.
>
> Send-Q
>          The count of bytes not acknowledged by the remote host.

Comment: note: the `netcat -U` command creates UNIX-domain socket, not TCP socket.

Answer (score 4):

[`ss`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) dumps `s`ocket `s`tatistics.  Netid `u_str` is abbreviation for `unix_stream` i.e., [AF_UNIX](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) socket family and [SOCK_STREAM](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) socket type:

> The `AF_UNIX` (also known as `AF_LOCAL`) socket family is used to
>          communicate between processes on the same machine efficiently.
>          Traditionally, UNIX domain sockets can be either unnamed, or bound to
>          a filesystem pathname (marked as being of type socket).  Linux also
>          supports an abstract namespace which is independent of the
>          filesystem.

> `SOCK_STREAM`     Provides sequenced, reliable, two-way, connection-
>                          based byte streams.  An out-of-band data transmission
>                          mechanism may be supported.

From [the quick intro to `ss` (`/usr/share/doc/iproute2-doc/ss.html`)](https://www.cyberciti.biz/files/ss.html):

> Then two columns (Recv-Q and Send-Q) showing amount of data queued for receive and transmit.

For unix sockets, it is [`unix_diag_rqlen`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/misc/ss.c?id=39be47fb5ed756b951ee7325b11099eb117fd5fd#n3135) from [`unix_diag.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/968edbd93c0cbb40ab48aca972392d377713a0c3/include/uapi/linux/unix_diag.h).